# Unity integrated into native iOS app. App crashes when closing Unity part and trying to reopen it

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine

After following [this](https://the-nerd.be/2015/11/13/integrate-unity-5-in-a-native-ios-app-with-xcode-7/) tutorial I managed to integrate a Unity app into a native iOS app. The problem I'm currently facing is when I try to go back from the Unity part to native iOS.

For Android I solved this by doing something like:

```
public void ReturnToNative()
{
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject jo = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject> ("currentActivity");
    jo.Call ("goBack");
#endif

#if UNITY_IOS
    Application.Quit();
#endif
}
```

The native Java method "goBack" basically stops and then finishes an activity that contains the Unity part.

I know that for iOS the solution is not an Application.Quit(), I should use an iOS Plugin.

So my question is, **what should this plugin do? How could I make it work?**

I know how to create plugins, but I don't know what this particular plugin should contain.

Any help / hint / direction / comment is greatly appreciated!!

PS. I'm using Unity 5.4.2 and Xcode 8.0. The Unity part uses the Google Cardboard SDK.

Comment: you said you tried making an ios plugin that would do something different to application quit. what was it?

Comment: @turnipinindia I added a .h file with `@interface UnityHider : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

- (void)hideUnityWindow;

@end` and a .m file with `#import "UnityHider.h"

@implementation UnityHider

- (void)hideUnityWindow {
    [[self window] makeKeyAndVisible];
}

@end`. I called the hideUnityWindow according to the Unity docs https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html. This code was given to me by the iOS dev, I only do the Unity part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a couple of months since this question, but in case anyone else runs into a similar issue, [here's](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1265774/issue-with-integration-into-native-ios-app.html?childToView=1357910#answer-1357910) how I managed to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

For using native plugins on iOS read the following info:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html

Comment: Thanks, I know how to create and use plugins. My question was related to **what** should the plugin do. I found a solution days after I posted the question, but I'm facing a few bugs in the project related to the integration. As soon as I solve these, I'll post my answer